# Option in World file to make camera follow model

Tags: gazebo-camera

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Is there a way to edit the world file to have the camera follow the model?  I am rerunning the same simulation right now and trying to save time instead of right-clicking my model and selecting "Follow"

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/21465/option-in-world-file-to-make-camera-follow-model/) by [variable](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/7373/variable/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 13 on 2018-12-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

To summarize, in case the tutorial changes...

You add the following to your .world file, which would track target_model from 3 meters behind it:

```
<gui fullscreen='0'>
     <camera name="user_camera">
        <track_visual>
          <name>target_model</name>
          <static>true</static>
          <use_model_frame>true</use_model_frame>
          <xyz>-3 0 0</xyz>
          <inherit_yaw>true</inherit_yaw>
        </track_visual>
    </camera>
</gui>
```

---

Originally posted by [variable](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/7373/variable/) with karma: 13 on 2018-12-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

There's a tutorial in a pull request right now: https://bitbucket.org/ocrave/gazebo_tutorials/src/1453d79f468ccbdaaa56236140c89a288e3e24f1/track_visual/tutorial.md?fileviewer=file-view-default

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2018-12-17

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1